# Changing text on JComponent

Tags: java, swing, repaint, jcomponent

I need to change text inside Jcomponents, which are arranged at the coordinates x and y on JPanel.
But if I change the text everywhere, except in the TextFields or PasswordFields, the location and dimensions of the elements slipping.

Listener, that changes parameters of elements

```
private TextListener textListener = new TextListener() {

    @Override
    public void textValueChanged(TextEvent e) {
        if (comp.getClass() == JButton.class) {
            ((JButton)comp).setText(ttext.getText());
        }else{
            if(comp.getClass() == JTextField.class){
                ((JTextField)comp).setText(ttext.getText());
            }else{
                if(comp.getClass() == JPasswordField.class){
                    ((JPasswordField)comp).setText(ttext.getText());
                }else{
                    if(comp.getClass() == JTextArea.class){
                        ((JTextArea)comp).setText(ttext.getText());
                    }else{
                            if(comp.getClass() == JCheckBox.class){
                                ((JCheckBox)comp).setText(ttext.getText());
                            }else{
                                ((JRadioButton)comp).setText(ttext.getText());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        try{
            comp.setBounds(tx,ty,Integer.valueOf(twidth.getText()),Integer.valueOf(theight.getText()));
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        comp.repaint();         
    }
};
```

What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: I use BorderLayout in General Frame, but in Panel, in which I put JComponents is no layouts.

Comment: `but in Panel, in which I put JComponents is no layouts` - well you should be using a LayoutManger. It is the job of the layout manager to determine the size of the component. Then you don't need to worry about a listener of any kind. You should not be using setBounds(). Also you should not be using a TextListener, that is for AWT components only.

Comment: Have you ever heard of `instanceof`? Instead of writing `if (comp.getClass() == JButton.class)` write instead `if(comp instanceof JButton)`. Even go one step further, use `AbstractButton` which is ancestor of both `JButton` and `JCheckBox` and use `JTextComponent` which is ancestor `JTextField`, `JPasswordField` and `JTextArea` (and others too). You can get your big `if else` down to 4 lines.

Answer (score 1):

- for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

  ---

> which are arranged at the coordinates x and y on JPanel

- [Component comp = myPanel.findComponentAt(x, y);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#findComponentAt%28int,%20int%29)

---

- `Component[] components = myPanel.getComponents();`
- then loop inside `components` arrays

  ```
      if (components[i] instanceof JLabel) {        
         JLabel myLabel = (JLabel) components[i];
         myLabel.whatever
      } else if (components[i] instanceof JButton) {
         JButton myButton = (JButton) components[i];
         myButton.whatever
      } and so on....,
  ```
- this/these temporary variable(s) in this form is valid only inside loop, but to suply real `JComponents`, and they are really changed
- you can to lost in `JFrame` and some `Compound JComponent`s doesn't returns real `JComponents` (`JPanel`, `JButton`, `JTextField`), returns `Objects` implemented in `BasicXxxUI`, but can be replaced with `JComponents`, or can use methods implemented for `JComponents`, for example editable `JComboBox` can returns `JTextField` or `JFormattedTextField` as editors component

---

- not good idea to hunting `JComponents` placed in `JPanel`, you need to know in all cases what, how, where, how much....

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the layout you use, but difficult to get a good answer when this information is not given.